# Getting a CSRF token is missing error when trying to upload an image to a flask app

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, csrf

I'm trying to upload an image to my flask app using flask-docs methods but this error keeps popping up:

```
400 Bad Request, CSRF Token is missing.
```

Here's the view functions:

```
# file uploading (avatar)
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


@login_required
@app.route('/upload_avatar', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def upload_avatar():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(url_for('user'))
        file = request.files.get('file', False)
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(url_for('user'))
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save = (os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], current_user.username))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename))
    return render_template('upload_avatar.html')


@login_required
@app.route('/uploaded_file')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
```

And this is the template:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Upload new File</title>
<h1>Upload new File</h1>
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input type=file name=file>
    <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
```

i do have csrf.protect initialized

```
csrf = CsrfProtect()


csrf.init_app(app)


UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/mnt/d/work/mysnsite/app/uploads/'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}
CKEDITOR_ENABLE_CSRF = True
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False

WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY = 'secretkey'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secretkey2'

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
```

I've tried adding `{{ form.csrf_token() }}` and `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}` but it doesn't seem to work as there is no form initialized in my view function..

Comment: https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html

Try adding :  
 <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>

Comment: yep, just tried that, seems to have worked, i'm no longer getting a csrf error, it's now internal server error, can you tell if my UPLOAD_FOLDER path is alright? I think the issue could be there, this is what i'm getting now `uploaded_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'`

Comment: fixed it by setting my filepath to `APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, r'static\uploads')`